# Login system just redirects you to the index page

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

My login system just redirects you to the index page even if the password is right, here are some files that may have the issue:

**LoginCheck.php:**

```
<?php
    require("header.inc.php");
    if (isset($_POST['submitButton'])) 
    {
        if(!isset($_POST['username']))
        {
            die("The username and password fields were not set.");
        }
        else if(!isset($_POST['password'])) 
        {
                die("Error: The password field was not set.");
        }

        $password = hash("sha512", $_POST['password']); 

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `name` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']) . "' AND `password` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($password) . "'");
        if(mysql_num_rows($query))
        {
            $sessID = mysql_real_escape_string(session_id());
            $hash = mysql_real_escape_string(hash("sha512", $sessID.$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']));
            $userData = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
            $expires = time() + (60 * 15);

            mysql_query("INSERT INTO `active_users` (`user`, `session_id`, `hash`, `expire`) VALUES ('" . (int) $userData['id'] . "', '" . $sessID . "', '" . $hash . "', '" . $expires . "')");
            header("Location: ./Dashboard.php");
            exit;
        }
        else {
            header("Location: ./index.php");
            exit;
        }
    }
    ?>
```

**Header.inc.php:**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require("connection.php");

    $user = IsLoggedIn();

    if($user)
    {
        $expires = time() + (60 * 15);
        mysql_query("UPDATE 'active_users' SET 'expires' = '" . $expires . "' WHERE 'user' = " . (int) $user . "");

    }

    function IsLoggedIn()
    {
        $sessID = mysql_real_escape_string(session_id());
        $hash = mysql_real_escape_string(hash("sha512", $sessID.$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']));

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT `user` FROM `active_users` WHERE `session_id` = '" . $sessID . "' AND `hash` = '" . $hash . "' AND `expires` > " . time(). "");

        $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
        if(mysql_num_rows($query))
        {
            return $data['user'];
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }

    }
    ?>
```

**Dashboard.php:**

```
<?php
require("header.inc.php");
if($user)
{
    print("Welcome to the dashboard!");
}
else {
    header("Location: ./index.php");
    end;
}
?>
```

**index page**

```
<?php
require("header.inc.php");
?>
<head>
<title>Zalman's UCP</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/main.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="Images/Favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
</head>
<body>

<div id="Youtube_Button"><img src="Images/Icons/Youtube Icon.png" width="34" height="28"></div>
<div id="Twitter_Button"><img src="Images/Icons/Twitter Icon.png" width="34" height="28"></div>
<div id="Line1"><img src="Images/line.png" width="10" height="605"></div>
<div id="container">
This is Zalman's, from scratch UCP, Development Stage: Alpha
<div id="Header">
<div id="Logo">
<center><a href="index.php">ZALMAN</a></center>
</div>
<div id="LoginBox"><center>Login in</center></div>
<div id="Login">

<?php
print("<form id=\"LoginForm\" method=\"post\" action=\"./LoginCheck.php\">\n");
print("Username: <input type=\"text\" name=\"username\" id=\"username\"/><br /><br />\n");
print("Password: <input type=\"password\" name=\"password\" id=\"password\"/><br /><br />\n");
print("<button type=\"submit\" name=\"submitButton\" id=\"sumbitButton\">Login</button>\n");
print("</form>\n");
 ?>
</div> 
</body>
```

The problem is that the password and username are both correct but when you type them in it just redirects you in the index page when it should redirect you to the Dashboard.php

Comment: Are you not able to debug your code? It's clear that `$user` is false - you should be able to debug and find out why.

Comment: Could you please post the database schema @Zalman as well as the file where you actually log in and the `index.php` file? Also you're using `end;` in the `else` clause in "Dashboard.php", I believe that should be `exit;`.

Comment: Furthermore, `expires` is an int so you shouldn't need to put SQL string delimiters around it `'` apostrophes. Take them out.